# recognition of character &#x0D; in java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, carriage-return

In my XML file, I have `&#x0D;`, i.e. carriage return, in some text nodes. How do I recognize a text that contains such character? I'm using the plain java DOM interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It seems it is comparable to `'\r'`. Hence, for example,

```
String text = //xml text that contains &#x0D;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    if (text.charAt(i) == '\r')
        // code...
```